# Using a score to assign an award in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is the last part of my issues for this project. I want to 'assign' an award based on the overall score (the average score of three judges). so if the score was 0-30 it would be a gold, 30.1-60 it would be a high gold, and lastly 60.1- 90 it would be a platinum. when the get score button is pressed I want the overall score to be shown (which it does) and the award assigned to be shown (gold, high gold, platinum). How can I get that award to be assigned and shown? I'm not sure how to code that. I have the bases of a if statements but I'm not sure if that will work. Need help figuring out how to find what the award is and having it show the award. like the overall score is calculated and shown. here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p align="right"> Dance Number:  <input type="text"size="3"></p>
<h1><ins>Judge 1</ins></h1>
<form>
<p> Technique:  <input class="jd1" id="txt1" type="number"size="3"   min="0" max="35">     /35</p>
<p> Choreography:  <input id="txt2" class="jd1" type="number"size="3"    min="0" max="15"> /15</p>
<p> Performance: <input  id="txt3" class="jd1" type="number"size="3" min="0" max="25">   /25</p>
<p> Precision:  <input id="txt4" class="jd1" type="number"size="3" min="0" max="15">  /15</p>
<p> Total Points: <input id="txt5"type="text"size="3">  /90</p>
<p> Comments</p>
<textarea name="commentsOne" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>
</br>
</form>

<h1><ins>Judge 2</ins></h1>
<form>
<p> Technique:  <input id="txt6" type="number" class="jd2" size="3" min="0"  max="35"> /35</p>
<p> Choreography:  <input id="txt7" type="number" class="jd2" size="3" min="0" max="15"> /15</p>
<p> Performance: <input id="txt8" type="number" class="jd2" size="3" min="0" max="25"> /25</p>
<p> Precision:  <input  id="txt9" class="jd2" type="number" size="3" min="0" max="15"> /15</p>
<p> Total Points: <input  id="txt10"type="number"size="3">  /90</p>
<p> Comments</p>
<textarea name="commentsOne" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>
</form>

<h1><ins>Judge 3</ins></h1>
<form>
<p> Technique:  <input  id="txt11" class="jd3" type="number"size="3"  min="0" max="35">  /35</p>
<p> Choreography:  <input id="txt12" type="number" class="jd3" size="3" min="0" max="15">  /15</p>
<p> Performance: <input  id="txt13" class="jd3" type="number" size="3" min="0" max="25">  /25</p>
<p> Precision:  <input id="txt14" type="number" size="3" class="jd3" min="0" max="15"> /15</p>
<p> Total Points: <input id="txt15" type="number"size="3">  /90</p>
<p> Comments</p>
<textarea name="commentsOne" cols="50" rows="5">
</textarea>
</form>

<input type="button"  onclick="sum()" onclick="award()" value="Get   Score">
<p> Overall Score:<span id="avg"></span></p>
<p> Award Assigned:<span id = "award"></span></p>
</body>
<script>

  function getSum(className) {
  var result = 0;
  var classGroup = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

  for(var i =0; i < classGroup.length; (i = i + 1))
  {
    result += parseInt((classGroup[i].value || 0), 10);
  }

  return result;

}

function sum() {

  var result1 = getSum('jd1');
  var result2 = getSum('jd2');
  var result3 = getSum('jd3');

  console.log('sum' + result1 + '' + result2 + '' + result3);

  document.getElementById('txt5').value = result1;
  document.getElementById('txt10').value = result2;
  document.getElementById('txt15').value = result3;


  document.getElementById('avg').innerHTML = (result1 + result2 +   result3)/3;
}

function award(){

document.getElementById('avg').value = x;

if( x = 0, x++, x < 30.1)
    {

    }

if( x = 0, x++, x < 60.1)
    {

    }

if( x = 0, x++, x < 91)
    {

    }
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you think `if( x = 0, x++, x < 30.1)` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var award = ['Gold','High Gold','Platinum'][ (( score - 0.1 ) / 30 ) | 0 ];
```

I was just curious if it could be done in one line of code without all those if statements ... and the answer is yes.  The line above returns the correct award for scores 0 to 91.

The interesting part here is the bitwise operator "score | 0". This works like Math.floor() for positive numbers and Math.ceil() for negative numbers. And that is just what is needed in this case to calculate the array index.

Well, we all know not to use tricks in production code unless the goal is to make other programmers hate you. Still, it's kind of cool.

**update:**

In response to comment, replace this line:

```
document.getElementById('avg').innerHTML = (result1 + result2 +   result3)/3;
```

with these lines:

```
var score = (result1 + result2 + result3) / 3;
document.getElementById('avg').innerHTML = score;
document.getElementById('award').innerHTML = ['Gold','High Gold','Platinum'][ (( score - 0.1 ) / 30 ) | 0 ];
```

Again, I don't encourage the use of tricks like this in production code - lol.

Comment: This is great! How can I print the award in the award assigned area though. like I did for the overall score. I have tried the  document.getElementById('award').innerHTML = award;
but it doesn't seem to work... any suggestions??

Comment: When I did that it worked but my sums for the judges gets messed up

Comment: I just tried it with the code from your post and it appeared to work okay. The only thing obviously wrong is that your "Get Score" button has 2 onclick methods assigned. Remove the second one that calls awards. Next step would be to watch the getSum() function in the debugger or by printing to the console.

Comment: I just got it to work, there was a letter missing on one thing that I must have missed when going through it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you change the if statements to something more like this it should work:

```
if(x < 30.1)
{

} 
else if(x < 60.1)
{

}
else if(x < 91)
{

}
```

The code `if( x = 0, x++, x < 30.1)` would only result in an error.

Comment: what do I put inside the curly bracets? like:

if(x < 30.1)
{
     high gold;
} 
else if(x < 60.1)
{
      gold;
}
else if(x < 91)
{
    platinum;
}


also how do I get it to show up next to the 'award assigned' are under the 'overall score' at the bottom when i hit the get score button???

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're mistaking `if` statement with for `loops`. The whole thing inside `if` should either return `true` or `false` (i.e. condition).

**EDITED:**

I changed the last few lines of your `sum()`, you make a call to `award()` passing the score;

```
function sum() {
    //your code
    var score = (result1 + result2 + result3) / 3;
    document.getElementById('avg').innerHTML = score;

    award(score);
}
```

And then your award function:

```
function award(x) {
    var aw = document.getElementById('award');

    if (x > 0 && x < 30.1)
        aw.innerHTML = 'Gold';
    else if (x < 60.1)
        aw.innerHTML = 'High Gold';
    else if (x < 91)
        aw.innerHTML = 'Platinum';
}
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/dLcn7a6d/)

Comment: where the gold, high gold and platium are, would  just put that? I'm still struggling on how to have that outputted like the overall score is

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out you are mistaking if statement with for loop. Also you have to assign the value of the element to x not vice versa.
You can try:

```
    function award(){
   var x = document.getElementById('avg').value ;
    var awardname='';
    if(x < 30.1)
        {
           awardname='gold';
        }

    if(x < 60.1)
        {
           awardname='high gold';
        }

    if( x < 91)
        {
           awardname='platinum';
        }

    document.getElementById('award').value = awardname;
    }
```